# Schedule import of local folder to Sharepoint library

Tags: document-library, synchronisation, sync

We have Sharepoint Server 2010 Enterprise SP1, inside this normal Document Library. We have application that stores files directoly to local server c:\files\*.pdf .

Is there any code-less solution that will schedule and every 1 minute check for files on local server c:\files\*.pdf and if they exists copy and delete (move) them to sharepoint library to given URL (https://mycorpsp:987/mydoclib) ?

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to configure this application to store the files in a different folder?

Comment: unfortunatley no :(

Comment: Then [mapping a document library as a network drive](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2005/08/31/244.aspx) is out of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no i don't think there is a codeless solution to this.. you most likely will have to do this via custom code.

You could create an console application which checks for files in the local folder, and if they do upload it to SharePoint and then set this application as Windows Scheduled Task with an Interval of 1min.

Another option would be implementing it using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. It fires when specific events happen in a directory like FileAdded, FileDeleted etc. You could hook into this events and perform the upload.

Maybe it's also possible to alter the application which stores the files so, that it uses the SharePoint WebServices directly, instead of saving the files to a local directory.

[Upload document to SharePoint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint)

Comment: I have created schedule to run every minute to my .vbs script. Script uses object MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0 and Filesystemobject.openAsTextstream to PUT files to Sharepoint library. However this does not work for files bigger than 2KB (.pdf) for example.